# Breaking down sums into frequency (for histogram)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing some analysis and I need a histogram but the data I need to work on is summed, table example below:

```
Item  Quantity  Cost
1         2       15
2         2       20
3         1       21
```

But in order to do the histogram I'd need the frequencies, so the table should look like:

```
Item  Quantity  Cost
1         1       15
1         1       15
2         1       20
2         1       20
3         1       21
```

Any idea on how to do it? Do I need a vba/macro to accomplish it?

Comment: @pnuts You are right... I miss-read the question -.-

Comment: Hi @pnuts the problem is (and I forgot to mention) the spreadsheet has thousands of rows

Comment: @pnuts in fact the first thing that came to my head was not a VBA approach, maybe it was a simple solution like pivot table tweak or even an add-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.  If not, it will at least get you started.

```
 Sub Expand_Occurance()
    Dim ItemCounter As Long, shBottom As Long, NewItemRow As Long, OccuranceCounter As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    shBottom = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get the bottom row of column 1
    NewItemRow = shBottom + 1 'and the first new row to write to

    For ItemCounter = 2 To shBottom
        If sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 2) > 1 Then 'there's more than one occurance
            'this could probably be more elegant, but it works
            Do While sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 2) > 1
                sh.Range(sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 1), sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 3)).Copy destination:=sh.Cells(NewItemRow, 1)
                sh.Cells(NewItemRow, 2) = 1
                NewItemRow = NewItemRow + 1
            sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 2) = sh.Cells(ItemCounter, 2) - 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next ItemCounter

'then sort the results
    shBottom = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get the new bottom row
    sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sh.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & shBottom), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sh.Sort
        .SetRange sh.Range("A1:C" & shBottom)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank, sir, that was exactly what I was looking for!!